# Updating to 5.11.0-36-generic kernel messed up my system

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, hdmi

After updating the kernel image to 5.11.0-36-generic the HDMI port stopped working and non of the networking interfaces worked. I had to revert back to an older kernel to use the system. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Are you using HWE?  20.04 uses kernel 5.4 unless you are using HWE.  5.4 is very stable

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not using HWE. So I reverted back to 5.4. The following wiki provide a good guide for how to do so: [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)